# Unit tests in JUnit failing when I run update/delete commands

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I am currently working on an API implementation in Java with spring and hibernate.

I have two tables in my Model package

User and UserDetail which has a OneToMany mapping

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String userId;
    private Set<UserDetail> userDetails;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<UserDetail> getUserDetails() {
        return userDetails;
    }

    public void setUserDetail(Set<UserDetail> userDetails) {
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
    }
}

@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String key;
    private String value;
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

My API looks like this

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public void addUserDetail(AddUserDetailRequest request) {
    //... adds the user detail for the userId as request.getUserId()
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public void deleteUserDetail(DeleteUserDetailRequest request) {
    //... deletes a particular value for a user with userId as request.getUserId() and userDetail key as request.getDeleteKey()
}
```

I have written Junit test cases to test the addition and deletion of UserDetails for a user, My addUserDetail is working as it should, but when I call the delete the changes are not reflected and they fail.

Below is my test case

```
@Test
public void testDeletUserDetail() throws Exception {
    //GIVEN
    String userId = client.newUser().call(getCreateUserRequest()).getId();
    client.newAddUserDetail().call(getAddUserDetailRequest(userId, "key1", "value1"));
    client.newAddUserDetail().call(getAddUserDetailRequest(userId, "key2", "value2"));

    //WHEN
    client.newDeteteUserDetail().call(getDeleteUserDetailRequest(userId, "key2"));

    //THEN
    List<UserDetail> userDetails = client.newGetUserDetail().call(getGetUserDetailRequest(userId));
    assertEquals(userDetails.size(), 1);  // This check fails and says it has a size of 2 instead of 1.
}
```

I am using HSQL for testing purposes

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.iiitd.myAPI.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" />
```

I have two implementation for deleteUserDetail and one of them fails.

```
// This one works in both jUnit and manual testing
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public void deleteUserDetail(DeleteUserDetailRequest request) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUserId(request.getUserId());
    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(user.getUserDetail())) {
        UserDetail toRemove = null;
        for(UserDetail userDetail : user.getUserDetail()) {
            if(StringUtils.equals(userDetail.getKey(), request.getDeleteKey())) {
                toRemove = userDetail;
            }
        }
        Assert.notNull(toRemove, "Detail  user doesn't exist.");
        user.getUserDetail().remove(toRemove);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}

//This one doesn't and unit tests fails but manual tests are OK
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public void deleteUserDetail(DeleteUserDetailRequest request) {
    UserDetail userDetail = userDetailRepository.getUserDetail();
    Assert.notNull(userDetail, "Detail doesn't exists");
    userDetailRepository.delete(userDetail);
}
```

All the repositories extends JpaRepository

Could anyone explain how to circumvent this issue ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that your test object may have more than one user detail; the first test sorts that out, the second does not. Have you tried to print those objects out?

Comment: The returned object has two entries but it should have only one entry with key = "key1" as the previous delete command has deleted one entry @UweAllner

Comment: Possibly you have other unit tests manipulating data? As they are executed in unpredictable order, do you have ensured clean circumstances (clean db etc.) for each?

Comment: It is annotated by @Transaction so all changes are reverted after the test is complete, There are many test, this particular instance happens when I try to call SELECT afer DELETE operation on the DB.